# How to remove symmetric margin from AlertDialog in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am showing `AlertDialog` when `ontap` `InkWell` all is well just one thing I don't know where this margin in top and bottom came from.

This is the result I've got

[image: img]

this is my code :

```dart
    AlertDialog(
      content: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text("PARACETAMOL MACROPHARMA 10 MG/ML",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "cairo-bold",
                  fontSize: 18),
            ),
            const Text("ANALGESIQUE ANTIPYRETIQUE",
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "cairo"),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  20, 5, 20, 5),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              child: const Text("PPV : 30.1 DH",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "cairo",
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Text(" PARACETAMOL / 1G",
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "cairo"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[],
     ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Center`  widget from `AlertDialog`'s `content`. It will be centered by default.

```dart
AlertDialog(
  content: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `center` widget and use `title`. Try this:

```
AlertDialog(
  title:  const Text(
    "PARACETAMOL MACROPHARMA 10 MG/ML",
    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "cairo-bold", fontSize: 18),
  ),
  content: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [

      const Text(
        "ANALGESIQUE ANTIPYRETIQUE",
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "cairo"),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 20, 5),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        ),
        child: const Text(
          "PPV : 30.1 DH",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: "cairo",
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const Text(
        " PARACETAMOL / 1G",
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "cairo"),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  actions: <Widget>[],
);
```